# I want to know how this graph is being created?

Tags: r, frequency, scatterplot

I found this plot in a paper. I have found similar plots in other papers from the same team. It is basically the comparison of MODIS C6 and C5 products with AERONET. I wanted to understand what that 'Frequency' color coding means and how was that calculated. I also have a data frame with AOD and AERONET data, but even if I am creating bins using AOD or AERONET column or even Bias (= AOD - AERONET) and counting the number of points within each of them and then color coding it, the result is not the same. Most points are at the bottom and hence they should have higher frequency, but that is not what is happening with me.

[image: Reference Image]

I used AOD (on the y-axis) to create the bins. As can be seen, my clusters are like bands, theirs is like a circle. I want to understand how they are doing it and if possible, some suggestions for functions in R on how to achieve it.

I don't know if I was able to express the issue correctly, so please let me know.

## -----

Code to create clusters.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(cluster = cut(AOD, breaks = 10, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE))

df_cluster_freq <- df %>%
  group_by(Sensor, cluster) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(cluster_frequency = n)

df <- df %>%
  left_join(df_cluster_freq, by = c("Sensor", "cluster"))
```

## ----

Code for plotting.

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes(x  = AERONET, y = AOD, color = cluster_frequency), size = 1.2) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x  = AERONET, y = upperEE), method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype="dashed", color = 'red', size = 1.1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x  = AERONET, y = lowerEE), method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype="dashed", color = 'red', size = 1.1) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x  = AERONET, y = AOD), method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = 'black') +
  theme_bw() + common_legend + #scale_color_distiller(palette = 'Spectral') + 
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "turbo") + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8), "cm")) +
  xlab("AERONET@550nm") + ylab("AOD@550nm")
```

[image: My image]

Comment: Please explain your graphic.  What's on the x-axis?  It's clear that if colors represent clusters, then you have used only the y-values for clustering and haven't incorporated the x-values at all.

Comment: I have AOD from some source on the y-axis and AERONET on the x-axis. I have updated the post. I have also added the code I used to create clusters.

Comment: How do I incorporate x-values as well?

Comment: There are a *huge* number of ways to create clusters: check out our [threads on clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cluster).  Your code doesn't appear to cluster at all--it just bins one variable.  It's unclear whether the paper is clustering or creating arbitrary bins or what it's doing; and it's also unclear whether you are trying to reproduce its colored scatterplots (which *don't* represent clusters at all) or to do something else.